# What method should we use instead of Hazelcast.getMap("Map")?

Tags: java, collections, hazelcast

I had been using `hazelcast-all-2.1 jar` previously. Recently I decided to migrate to version 2.5.1. I found out that the `Hazelcast.getMap("Map")` method is deprecated in the recent versions. So what is the alternative available for this method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get the map from the instance you have created. Static methods which give the default instance have been depracated.

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
IMap map = instance.getMap("map");
```